# "This domain is not authorized" when using Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently following a tutorial on [this link](http://time2hack.com/2015/03/intro-to-firebase-with-javascript-and-jquery.html)

I get the following error.

> firebase.js:75 Uncaught Error: This domain is not authorized for OAuth
>   operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized
>   domains from the Firebase console.

Do I need to create a Authentication system first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go on Firebase Panel, activate the signup method (Email/Password in this case) and then add your domain on the list of authorized domains:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-configuring