# Why does a Cloud Function for Firebase (deployed without errors), throw "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: internal" when called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am making an onCall function to do crud operations with the admin-sdk, create, read, update and delete users, and customClaims, but when calling the deployed function it throws the following errors in the browser console (the client is web):

*POST http://localhost:5001//southamerica-east1/usersCrud net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*

*Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: internal*

This is the function code:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.usersCrud = functions
  .region("southamerica-east1")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth || !context.auth.token.rol === "Supervisor") {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("Permission denied", "ERROR6", {
        error,
      });
    }

    switch (data.operation) {
      case "get":
        return listAllUsers()
          .then((listUsersResult) => {
            let users = [];
            listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
              users.push(userRecord.toJSON());
            });
            return users;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
              "Error getting users",
              "ERROR0",
              { error }
            );
          });
        break;

      case "del":
        return deleteUser(data.uid);
        break;

      case "cre":
        return createUser(data.user);
        break;

      case "upd":
        return updateUser(data.uid, data.user);
        break;

      default:
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("Operation wrong", "ERROR5");
        break;
    }
  });

const listAllUsers = async () => {
  return await admin.auth().listUsers(20);
};

const deleteUser = async (uid) => {
  return await admin
    .auth()
    .deleteUser(uid)
    .then(() => {
      return { deletedUser: uid };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("Error deleting user", "ERROR1", {
        error,
      });
    });
};

const createUser = async (newUserData) => {
  const { displayName, email, rol, sucursal } = newUserData;

  if (!displayName || !email || !rol || !sucursal) {
    return { message: "Missing fields" };
  }
  try {
    const { uid } = await admin.auth().createUser({ displayName, email });
    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { rol, sucursal });
    return { createdUser: uid };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("Error creating user", "ERROR3", {
      error,
    });
  }
};

const updateUser = async (uid, updatedUser) => {
  const { displayName, email } = updatedUser;
  return await admin
    .auth()
    .updateUser(uid, { displayName, email })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      return admin
        .auth()
        .setCustomUserClaims(uid, {
          rol: updatedUser.rol,
          sucursal: updatedUser.sucursal,
        })
        .then(() => {
          return { updatedUser: userRecord.toJSON() };
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("Error updating user", "ERROR4", {
        error,
      });
    });
};
```

I don't think it's an error in the code itself, because with the Emulator Suite it works correctly,
I think it's more an error with the admin sdk or credentials but I'm not sure. I obviously set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable before deploying the function, but calling it on the client gives me the same error

I need help

Comment: Because of the credentials problem, this sounds someway similar to what happened us already twice suddenly in the middle of project developments when they where already deployed for tests:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034865/1920145

Comment: **Connected refused** means that nobody is listening for connections on TCP port 5001 on localhost. Since the error message is occurring in the user's browser, you have a configuration mistake someplace. localhost would be the user's computer. Edit your question and show where the URL is generated and used: http://localhost:5001//southamerica-east1/usersCrud